# FeathersUI , Starling StageOrientation Event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, orientation, screen-orientation, starling-framework

when i change the orientation in mobile application , i change the viewPort of Starling to take new Height and new Width:

```
    var viewPort:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.fullScreenWidth,stage.fullScreenHeight);
    Starling.current.viewPort = viewPort;
```

but there is a problem the feathers UI components change : from image1 :
[image: image 1 (Default Orientation)]

to image2 :
[image: image 2 (rotatedLeft or rotatedRight Orientation)]
What is the main problem in Starling StageOrientation ??
any one have an idea ??

Comment: Hi Sameer. Images are too small to understand what going on there.This is little bit specific question , so may be you should try to ask Josh Tynjala (author of FeathersUI) , you can find him here: http://joshblog.net/.

Comment: Or may be if you add "FeathersUI" to the title of the question , Josh will see it here and will come to help